# replace Select tag with toggle switch

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I am using a select tag in the project to change the theme o the site. that is working like a charm in my project but I want to replace **select** tag with a **toggle switch** with jquery integration. Like, youtube to switch dark theme.
How can I do this

This is my code.

HTML, JS and JQuery

```js
$(function() {
  $('.style-change').change(function() {

    var style = $(this).val();
    $('body').fadeOut("slow", function() {
      $('link[rel="stylesheet"]').attr("href", style + ".css");
      $('body').fadeIn("slow");

      $.cookie("css", style, {
        expires: 365,
        path: '/'
      });
    });
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#style").val('<?php echo $style; ?>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<select name="" class="style-change form-control" id="style">
  <option value="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min">Default Style</option>
  <option value="https://bootswatch.com/3/darkly/bootstrap.min">Night Mode</option>
</select>
```

PHP

```
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE['css'])) {
    $style = $_COOKIE['css'];
} else {
    $style = 'default';
}
?>
```

I'm using jQuery cookie library to save user setting in cookies.

Any suggestion would be appreciable.

[A DEMO page](https://prog-hub.blogspot.com/2018/05/jquery-styleshhet-switching-fullwidth.html)

Comment: A toggle Switch can be made using a checkbox. Are you sure you want to use select tag only?

Comment: I want to replace the select tag with toggle switch like youtube dark theme switching.  @abhiox

Answer (score 0):

> Refer to this, may this will help you - https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-To-Convert-Select-Box-Into-A-Switch-Control-Switch-Button.html

Basic Usage:

1. Load jQuery library and the jQuery switch button plugin in the document.
2. Create a regular select box.

   ```
     <option value="1">Item One</option>

     <option value="2">Item Two</option>

     <option value="3">Item Three</option>

     <option value="4" selected>Item Four</option>


   </select>
   ```
3. Call the plugin to convert it into a toggleable switch button.

   $('.btn-switch').switchButton();
4. Add your custom styles to this switch button.

   .switch-select {

   ```
     overflow: hidden;

     border-radius: 3px;

   }



   .switch-select-button {

     text-align: center;

     font-size: 80%;

     padding: 5px;

     cursor: pointer;

     background: rgb(224, 224, 224);

   }


   .switch-select-button:hover {

     background: rgb(207, 55, 55);

     color: white;

   }
   ```
5. Available options.

   template: "", // custom template

   ```
   class: "switch-select", // element class

   innerclass: "switch-select-button", // inner element class

   width: "", // default to its parent width

   marker: "#3577EE, // marker color

   markerback: "#B9B9B9", // marker background color

   markerh: "4px", // marker size

   onchange: "function(value){}" // callback function
   ```

Comment: I use it but not work in my project.  Here is implemented Codepen. https://codepen.io/f86597/pen/gzoXpx

Answer (score 0):

You can use a checkbox and toggle using pure CSS.

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {
  display: none;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  transition: .4s;
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  transition: .4s;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  transform: translateX(26px);
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: Sir, How can I integrate with jQuery?   @Gerard

Comment: with actually using a checkbox, you lose the ability to use multiple value attributes from the select options....